# sci-fi book where a meteorite gives 3 different kinds of telepathic powers to people who then vie for control

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

3 groups of telepaths each with different powers.  They received their powers from a meteorite.  One group is the strongest and are kind of in control.  Another group wants to gain control.  One group, I believe the strongest, have telepathic battles to determine the strength of one another conjuring up swords, walls, etc. in their minds. It was written by a lawyer.  Could have been written in the ‘80s, or earlier.

Comment: Reminds me of [Chronicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicle_(film)), though that's a film from 2012 and not based on any existing script.

Comment: It is similar, but yes, this was a book and not very well known.  My mother picked it up for me in a library book sale knowing I love sci-fi.  It was a great story and I kept the book until I lost it in a move.  I’d love to remember the name!  Thanks for the comment!!